# ASP .NET MVC 6 Oracle Connection String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

What is the correct format of the Oracle connection string in MVC 6?

My dependencies:

```
"EntityFramework": "5.0.0",
"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess": "12.1.2400",
"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework": "12.1.2400",
```

My connection string :

```
{

  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Data Source=myHost:myPort/mydb;User Id=myUser;Password=myPassword"      
    }
  }
}
```

Reported error:

```
{"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."}
```

In MVC 5 I use this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App.csdl|res://*/App.ssdl|res://*/App.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=myHost:myPort/myDb;PASSWORD=myPassword;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=myUser;Connection Timeout=900&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: The MVC 5 string isn't an Oracle connection string, it's an EF model-first connection string. What are you using in the MVC 6 project? Did you try to store an EF string?

Comment: I need to connect the oracle in my DbContext , how to do this in asp.net 6 using appsettings.json file? thanks.

Comment: The error mentions an inner exception. Please post the *full* exception, not just Exception.Message. You can get the full text using `Exception.ToString()`. Why aren't you using the *same* connection string though? Have you also moved from model-first to code-first?

Answer (score 0):

In your Example your are using Managed Driver as Data Provider to use oracle DB.
 But in your EF connection string your are mentioning different Provider (providerName="System.Data.EntityClient") while you should use (providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client")

See correct connection string below :

```
<add name="TestContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=test;Password=testpassword;Data Source=eftest" />
```

For more details Please refer to the following link :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/InstallEntityConfig.htm#ODPNT8266